# Mui autocomplete component display empty list when options prop is empty

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
<Autocomplete
  id="recordlist"
  freeSolo
  options={[""]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      {...params}
      label="record"
    />
  )}
/>
```

When using the above code Autocomplete add an empty list unneeded box as shown in the picture below:

[image: empty list]

how do I remove this empty box when the options list is empty? the options list get filled later when options are received from the server. but initially I want not to have any options and remove this strange empty option box.

Answer (score 1):

You're still giving an option `""`. Replace it with an empty array `options={[]}`